# Stuck on final SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm busy creating a report and am stuck with how to structure the final query.  I have a sub-query that returns the following result set

[image: Sub-query Result]

I need the final query result to look like this:

[image]

I know I can get there with an over engineered query, but would rather do it the right way, while also learning something new. Would really appreciate any help or suggestions.  Thanks

PS Using Microsoft SQL Server 2014

Comment: What version of SQL do you have?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2014

Comment: Can AirContractIDFK have more then 2 ID's?  IE it's a 1 to N situation?  Cause if it only happens at most twice, there is a very easy brute force answer.

Comment: No,  it's a 1 to N relationship

Comment: Please post sample data as a plain text not images.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sample of code that should do what you are expecting it to do.

```
CREATE TABLE #T (
    AircontractIDFK INT
    ,DepCity CHAR(3) 
    ,SeatsHeld INT
)

INSERT INTO #T(
    AircontractIDFK
    ,DepCity
    ,SeatsHeld
)
SELECT
    AircontractIDFK
    ,DepCity
    ,SeatsHeld
FROM
    (VALUES (1175, 'JFK', 29)
            ,(4385, 'CLT', 27)
            ,(4385, 'CVG', 2)
            ,(4389, 'ORD', 7)
            ,(4389, 'ORD', 24)) AS T (AircontractIDFK, DepCity, SeatsHeld)

;WITH CTE_T AS(
    SELECT
        AircontractIDFK
        ,DepCity
        ,SUM(SeatsHeld) AS SeatsHeld
    FROM
        #T
    GROUP BY
        AircontractIDFK
        ,DepCity
)
SELECT
    *
    ,STUFF((SELECT ',' + ST.DepCity + '(' + CAST(ST.SeatsHeld AS VARCHAR(10)) + ')' FROM CTE_T ST  WHERE ST.AircontractIDFK = T.AircontractIDFK  FOR XML PATH('')), 1,1,'')

FROM
    CTE_T T
```

Comment: Serg!  Teach me how to do that code box thing.  I'm too new at this!  For clarification, I had it nicely formatted in SSMS but when I copy pasted... formatting went poof.

Comment: Pay attention to the tollbox above the edited text. When editing the question select the text an apply `{}` formatting.

Comment: Don't know why, but I noticed, in my own code, I missed a group by clause at the end there.  Should have only returned 3 records that you wanted.  As the code is now, it returns 4 records.  If you add (at the bottom) "Group By T.AircontractIDFK" it will go down to 3 records.

Answer (score -1):

I have this query executed in SQL server 2014:

```
SELECT AircontactIDFK, STRING_AGG(DepCity+' ('+CAST(SeatsHeld as nvarchar(10))+') ',',') as Seats
FROM Airport
GROUP BY AircontactIDFK
```

Here's the result:
[image]
Please let me know if it works for you?

Comment: `STRING_AGG` doesn't exist in SQL Server 2014

Comment: `STRING_AGG()` was introduced in SQL Server 2017!